# In clause with And operation

Tags: mysql

I have records like this....

```
oid        id

35         1

43         1

46         1

43         2

49         2

50         3

51         3

52         4
```

I have id=1 and 2 . I want those results which belong to both the both the ids(1,2) only.

i.e - o/p = recodrds of object_id = 43 because it is belonging to both 1 and 2.

if I use **in** operator then it is giving all the records (performing OR operaion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `IN` operator but then use a GROUP BY with a HAVING clause to return only those rows with a DISTINCT count of 2:

```
select oid
from yourtable
where id in (1,2)
group by oid
having count(distinct id) = 2;  
                          --^ change this number to the count of ids in IN clause
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9280/1)

Answer (score 1):

This is a generic, fast solution to this kind of problems.

1. Get all IDs (in this case oid values) that staisfy our condition:
   `select oid from MyTalbe
   where id in (1,2)
   group by oid
   having count (distinct id) >1`
2. Select rows where IDs ('oid` column) IN list of IDs we need:

   select oid, id from Mytable 
   where oid in 
     (select oid from MyTalbe
      where id in (1,2)        -- This is the same as: where id =1 or id=2
      group by oid
      having count (distinct id) >1
     )

Comment: please check my updated question,... actually I have more results and I have id=1,2 and i need results of these 2 ids

Comment: Updated. When you want specific values you use `WHERE` clause.

Comment: It is there. we select and count only rows `where id in (1,2)`.

Comment: but it is giving me all the results of 1 and 2.

Comment: Do you want just a list of distinct `oid` where there is an `id =1`  and `id =2`?

Comment: This will not work properly. See this demo -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9280/6 -- if an oid has two rows with a 1 and none with a 2, then the oid will be returned.

Comment: @bluefeet I'll add `count (distinct )`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT t.oid FROM table1 t
WHERE t.oid IN (SELECT oid FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.oid=t.oid AND t1.id = 1)
AND t.oid IN (SELECT oid FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.oid=t.oid AND  t1.id = 2)
GROUP BY oid
```

Comment: but i have id=1 and 2 . I want results of both the 2s